# angular foundation modals, can't send back information

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation, angular-foundation

I am using an integration of foundations modals with angular (http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/) and am having trouble with the modal sending back the proper information on close: Here's what I have

the modal:

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="dataBlockType.html">
            <h4>Select Type</h4>
            <select ng-model="blockTHereSelect" ng-options="type.name for type in items track by type.id">
            </select>
            {{blockTHereSelect.name}}
              <button class="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal" ng-click="cancel()">&#215;</a>
        </script>

        <!-- type modal -->
```

The modal functions in the controller it's inside :

```
$scope.openModal = function () {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'dataBlockType.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                  return $scope.dataTypes;
                }
              }
        });

        //return of modal
         modalInstance.result.then(function (returnAns) {
            $scope.storeTempName = returnAns;

            console.log($scope.storeTempName);
                 //push new information from modal in
                $scope.dataBlockstypes.push({id:"",name: "" , blocks: [], typeId: "" });

            }, function () {
              //return function if needed
            });
          };
```

The modal controller:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

    $scope.blockTHereSelect = {};
    //bring in retuned list to populate modal select list
     $scope.items = items;

     //pass back selection
  $scope.ok = function () {

       $modalInstance.close($scope.blockTHereSelect);
  };

  //close
  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

So this works fine for passing information to populate the modal from the original controller (yay). But Where I seem to be having issues is passing back the selected options name and id. My thinking was if i just pass back the model attached to it ($scope.blockTHereSelect), it would pass and object which i could then call .id and .name on. However it's coming back as an empty object and if i try to send $scope.blockTHereSelect.id and $scope.blockTHereSelect.name individually they come back undefined. I seem to be a little stumped, I think it might be in something with how the models or scopes work within the modal controller. Would appreciate any help, can't seem to solve this.
Thanks!!

Comment: are you actually using angular-foundation? http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/  I found a lot of issues trying to DIY.

Comment: Yes, I am using exactly that. I am trying to pretty much follow their example, and it worked great until I couldn't get the selected option to send back.

Comment: Does it return anything if you just pass back one property (id) of the object, rather than the object itself? Unless I misunderstood your previous attempts.

Comment: I feel a little silly, All i needed to do was pass the object back to the modal controlller buy doing ng-click="ok(blockTHereSelect)"